# Handling of Null Values

Tags: c#, oracle

I had an bizarre situation while debugging my code today.

As the screen shot says, I had an `object obj` yields a value from an `System.Data.OracleClient` `ExecuteScalar()`.

The yielded value was assigned to variable obj which clearly shows its a null, but the execution had gone inside a `if (obj != null)` statement which technically should not. Anything idea? I wonder I did the code correct?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value(v=vs.110).aspx) instead

```
if(obj != DBNull.Value)
```

Comment: Is obj really DBNull.Value? In the screenshot I see a IsNull and Value property.

Comment: This is what the confusion was

Comment: @Dirk To clear that up: if a value is truly `null` then it has no preperty at all. It would only display `null` as the value of `obj` in a single line.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste And DBNull.Value doesn't have a IsNull or Value property. Actually my answer below answers the question about the return type.

Answer (score 4):

DBNull.Value can be used,

null is not an instance of any type. Rather, it is an invalid reference.

However, System.DbNull.Value, is a valid reference to an instance of System.DbNull (System.DbNull is a singleton and System.DbNull.Value gives you a reference to the single instance of that class) that represents nonexistent* values in the database.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [`ExecuteOracleScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.executeoraclescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) says that it "executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query as an **Oracle-specific data type**."

From what I can tell the result could be an [`OracleNumber`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclenumber(v=vs.110).aspx) for example, which has the properties `IsNull` and `Value` as your screenshot shows.

Comment: you explanation is correct. I ran the SQL, which returned no rows, technically a null value. The SQL was supposed to return an `OracleNumber` value, but `ExecuteOracleScalar()` returned an OracleNumber type with its Value attribute as `null` since there were no rows.